# Am I missusing Form::handleRequest

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

## Background:

I have built a form which bulk-edits multiple entities of the same type at the same time. The form works correctly as is, it can save the changes made to the exposed fields.

I initialize the form data with an array of entities fetched from the database. `$form->handleRequest($request)` is using the same array of entities to identify which entity has changed and use its setters to alter its changed properties.

Unfortunately `$form->handleRequest($request)` is identifying the correspondence between a the form data and the entities based on the array index of the entities.

This means that if the data would change in the DB in such a way that the sorting would change the `$form->handleRequest($request)` would try to update the wrong entity object because the sort order wouldn't exactly match.

### Correction attempts:

1. I added the `id` as a hidden field in the form hoping Symfony2 would use it to initialized the object to be updated...

   ...but Symfony2 tried to use `setId($newId)` and I didn't have a setter defined for that property. So I added the setter and I made it throw an exception if the `$newId !== $this->id` -- which it does -- if you switch the rows around, or try to save only one row (via ajax) or if you delete rows from the form (via JS).
2. I tried to use INDEX BY in the query that fetches the entities hoping the matcher algorithm is matching date>entities by array keys... didn't work either.

### Question:

I am obviously going about this the wrong way. I'm not using something the way it was designed to be used.

Symfony2 probably has another workflow for bulk-updating stuff. Perhaps handleRequest should only be used when the form is initialized on an entity by ID. Perhaps I should just not use `handleRequest` and build my own custom logic for updating what changed.

## Code:

### Controller:

```
class AAAAController extends Controller
{
    public function AAAAEditAction(Request $request, $filters)
    {
        $AAAAs = $AAAArepo->findBy($filters);

        $form = $this->createForm(new MultiAAAAType(), array('AAAAs' => $AAAAs))
            ->handleRequest($request);

        foreach ($AAAAs as $AAAA) {
            $em->persist($AAAA);
        }
        $em->flush();
    }
}
```

### Main form (containing one single collection field):

```
class MultiAAAAType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            'single_aaaa',
            'collection',
            array(
                'type' => new SingleAAAAType(),
            )
        );
    }
}
```

### Sub-form (containing the particular fields that need to be edited):

```
class SingleEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        // adding actual fields here
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => '\...\Entity\AAAA',
            )
        );
    }
}
```

### Also:

I know that `$form->submit` used to be the norm (as used [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313981/update-relation-vial-bulk-with-symfony2-form)) and `handleRequest` calls `submit` after doing the matching.

I agree that doing the matching by hand wouldn't be all that bad if I use `$em->merge` to update the entities. The solution would be a few lines of code (as in the answer I mentioned).

But the question at hand is "Am I doing this wrong? Should I be using the above solution? Wasn't `handleRequest` designed to handle this case?".

If `handleRequest` can't handle this case that means it can't handle associations properly either without getting into this very same pickle.

Comment: Have you looked into data transformers which will retrieve the entities for you on submit.  This way the filters won't need to be consistent with the data in the event the data has changed.

Comment: @Flosculus Do you mean `@ParamConverter`?

Comment: Scrap that, I misunderstood your problem.  To avoid conflicts I would perform a check to see if the data has changed prior to submitting the form (on the server side), report the conflict to the user if there is one.  Otherwise you are stuck trying to dynamically sync the submission with additional conditions the user might not be made aware of.

Comment: Dynamically syncing the submission wouldn't be that much of a problem if I use `INDEX BY`. The Doctrine Results would have the ID in its array key, form will have the ID in its array key -- BAM! synced with a single foreach.

Comment: It just looked so cool having a one-liner that updates your data.

Comment: Oh and did I mention `$form->submit` is supposed to be deprecated -- so relying on it shouldn't be OK... then if `submit` is off limits, how would you solve this issue.

Comment: Sending the request through `submit` is deprecated, you can still use to send an array of submission data. Look into form event subscribers, there is not standard to in internals of forms, event subscribers allow you do implement as you like.

Comment: Makes sense... I'm trying it now.

Comment: Well it obviously works now -- including single-update ajax calls. And the neat part about using the answer I mentioned. But here's the strange thing: `foreach ($form->get('AAAAs')->all() as $AAAAForm) $AAAAForm->getData()` gives me an `$AAAA` object which I then `$em->merge($AAAA)` -- So basically I'm not doing the matching, the identityMap inside Doctrine is doing it. So why doesn't `handleRequest` do the same bloody thing?